# How to get data from a LINQ query call for anonymous type dataset

Tags: c#, linq

I have this LINQ query.

```
var sumOfData = fullData.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { x.transactionId, x.checkId }).
        Where(p => (p.Key.checkId == variable.checkId) && (p.Key.transactionId == variable.transactionId))
        .Select(y => new
        {
                checkId = variable.checkId,
                transactionId = variable.transactionId,
                SumAppliedAmt = y.Sum(z => z.appliedAmount),
                SumCheckAmt = y.Sum(x => x.checkAmount)
        });
```

How can I access the data inside `sumOfData`?

What would I need to do to access `sumOfData.checkId` or `sumOfData.transactionId`?
I want to access it without using the foreach loop. Sorry I forgot to add that part. I am already access one LINQ using `foreach (var data in fullDataQuery)` and putting a foreach inside the foreach would be performance intensive { if (data.invoiceBalance==) }

Also is it possible to directly update to

```
var fullDataQuery = remitFile.AsEnumerable().Select(
                remitInfofullData => new
                    {
                        checkId = remitInfofullData.Field<int>("checkId"),
                        depositId = remitInfofullData.Field<int>("depositId"),
                        appliedAmount = remitInfofullData.Field<decimal>("appliedAmount"),
                        checkAmount = remitInfofullData.Field<decimal>("checkAmount"),
                        invoiceBalance = remitInfofullData.Field<decimal>("invoiceBalance"),
                        sequenceId = remitInfofullData.Field<int>("sequenceId"),
                        remittanceId = remitInfofullData.Field<int>("remittanceId"),
                        fileId = remitInfofullData.Field<int>("fileId"),
                        transactionId = remitInfofullData.Field<int>("transactionId"),

                    }).Where(p => (p.checkId == variable.checkId) && (p.transactionId == variable.transactionId)); using    var sumOfData = fullData.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(x => new { x.transactionId, x.checkId }).
    Where(p => (p.Key.checkId == variable.checkId) && (p.Key.transactionId == variable.transactionId))
    .Select(y => new
    {
            checkId = variable.checkId,
            transactionId = variable.transactionId,
            SumAppliedAmt = y.Sum(z => z.appliedAmount),
            SumCheckAmt = y.Sum(x => x.checkAmount)
    }); the sumAppliedAmount value
```

Comment: Can you tell me what type `fullData` is?  If you're using LINQ to SQL or the Entity Framework or some other query provider that connects to a database, using `AsEnumerable()` in advance of your filters is going to cause your code to loop through every row in the table and apply your filter on the client side, instead of letting the database do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @JeremyTodd: I assume it a strongly typed `DataSet` since it has properties and he mentioned `DataSet` in the title. So it's `Linq-To-DataSet(Linq-To-Objects)`.

Comment: Ah, yeah -- should've looked at the title. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can access it like any other collection. For example you can iterate the items using a `foreach`:

```
foreach (var item in sumOfData)
{
    //access properties on item by using item.checkId,
    //item.transactionId, item.SumAppliedAmt, item.SumCheckAmt
    //do your stuff
}
```

To access it **without a `foreach`**, you can use LINQ to do things like get the item with the highest check amount:

```
var highestCheckAmtItem = sumOfData.OrderByDescending(s => s.SumCheckAmt).First();
```

Comment: I want to access it without using the foreach loop. Sorry I forgot to add that part.

Comment: @user2358826 Why?  What do you want to accomplish that couldn't be done with a `foreach`?

Comment: SumofData only returns back a single record even if it is a collection

Comment: @user2358826 Then after the `Select`, just do `.First()`. Then you can do `sumOfData.transactionId` or whatever property you want.

Comment: @user2358826: I haven't downvoted, however, if you want to avoid them or if you want that people remove their downvotes you should add details that you've commented instead to your question. You can always edit it, make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

You could for example use `foreach` to enumerate the query:

```
foreach (var x in sumOfData)
{
    var transactioID = x.transactionId;
    var checkId = x.checkId;
    var sumAppliedAmt = x.SumAppliedAmt;
    var sumCheckAmt = x.SumCheckAmt;
}
```

or you use `ToList` to create a `List<YourAnonymousType>`. But since you can use this anonymous type only in this method you should use a real class if you want to use it in different places.

Comment: I want to access it without using the foreach loop. Sorry I forgot to add that part. I am already access one LINQ using  foreach (var data in fullDataQuery) and putting a foreach inside the foreach would be performance intensive 
                    {
                         if (data.invoiceBalance==)
                    }

Comment: @user2358826 If that's important to your question then *add it to your question*.

Answer (score 1):

`sumOfData` is a collection, not a single value. You can do something like:

```
foreach (var element in sumOfData)
{
   Console.Write("CheckID is "+ element.checkId);
   Console.Write("transactionId  is "+ element.transactionId);
   Console.Write("SumAppliedAmt  is "+ element.SumAppliedAmt);
   Console.Write("SumCheckAmt  is "+ element.SumCheckAmt);
}
```

Or, you can transform it into a regular list / array by using `ToList()` and `ToArray` respectively.
Also, if you are, for example, sure that the collection will have just a single element (since you are filtering of the checkId/transactionId combination) you can use `First` or `Single`, like this:

```
var sumOfData = fullData
                .AsEnumerable()
                .GroupBy(...)
                .Where(...)
                .Select(...)
                .First();
```

which will return the first element of the collection, removing the need of a `foreach`, so you can do

```
Console.Write("CheckID is "+ sumOfData.checkId);
Console.Write("transactionId  is "+ sumOfData.transactionId);
Console.Write("SumAppliedAmt  is "+ sumOfData.SumAppliedAmt);
Console.Write("SumCheckAmt  is "+ sumOfData.SumCheckAmt);
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response. I was amazed with the speed with which I got my answers. Great help everybody .Thanks again